How to get Row values as columns like PIVOT in postgresql
I have a table called Product and it has columns like
Product_Id integer
Product_Code varchar

and also have a table called Product_Values and it has column like
Product_Id Integer
Product_Name Varchar

When i join these two tables on the Product_Id, I got below data.



Product_Code
Product_Name




Country
USA


Country
Newzeland


Country
Australia


Country
India


State
Chicago


State
Mexico


State
Capetown


State
Sydney


State
Hyderabad


State
Mumbai


State
Delhi



Here my requirement is,I want to get Product_Code as columns and Product_name as it row values
as shown below



Country
State




USA
Chicago


Newzealand
Mexico


Australia
Chicago


India
Capetown



Sydney



Hyderabad



Mumbai



Since Product_Code column does not have fixed values, I want dynamic query like to display all the available product_code values as columns and product_name as its row values.
Please help me with the dynamic query in postgresql.

You can use crosstab or aggregate filter clause. If the list of values is really dynamic, that'll have to go into a PL/pgSQL DO/routine block allowing you to dynamically construct the final query and execute it. It gets unsightly.

Hold on, how exactly do you match the Countries to States? Right now it looks like you just want to get a list of unique Countries in one column, randomly matched list of unique States in the other. Can you elaborate on what the logic is, and what do you intend to use this for?

If you meant to just get values per code, it might be easier and more efficient to not attempt the pivot and instead get them as an array of Product_Values for each Product_Code:
select product_code,array_agg(product_name)
from Product join Product_Values using (Product_Id)
group by product_code;




product_code
array_agg




State
{Chicago,Mexico,"Cape Town",Sydney,Hyderabad,Mumbai,Delhi}


Country
{USA,"New Zealand",Australia,India}



It might be way easier to process that in other parts of your app than forcing the column thing.
If you really want to have them in (misaligned) columns, you can loop over distinct Product_Codes and for each, construct a two-column subquery table expression: one column with Product_Values, one with their corresponding row number.
Then you can build your final output table by stitching those with natural full outer join. The natural makes it automatically join on the row number, full outer will keep listing Product_Values with matching row numbers, then continue listing them on their own when the other columns run out of values to match.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
create procedure pivot_test_table(output_table text)language plpgsql AS $f$
declare rec record;
        query_body text;
        query_per_column text:='(select row_number()over()n
                                       ,product_name as %1$I
                                 from Product 
                                 join Product_Values using (Product_Id)
                                 where product_code=%1$L) as %2$I';
begin 
  for rec in select distinct product_code from Product 
  loop
  query_body:=concat_ws(' natural full outer join '
                        ,query_body
                        ,format( query_per_column
                                ,rec.product_code
                                ,rec.product_code||'_subquery'));
  end loop;
  execute format( 'drop table if exists %1$I cascade;
                   create table %1$I as select * from %s;'
                   --||'alter table %1$I drop column n;'
                 ,output_table
                 ,query_body);
end $f$;

call pivot_test_table('pivot_test_table_result');
select * from pivot_test_table_result order by 1;




n
State
Country




1
Chicago
USA


2
Mexico
New Zealand


3
Cape Town
Australia


4
Sydney
India


5
Hyderabad
null


6
Mumbai
null


7
Delhi
null



You can't have a function that would return those directly because PostgreSQL needs to be able to determine the number, names and types of output columns at the start of the query, and here it's entirely dynamic. Dumping the result to a table and reading from it in a separate step, works around the limitation, but you need to be careful how you call it: repeated calls to the procedure that re-use the output table name will overwrite each other's results. You can use temp tables and randomise their names.
To get rid of the n column, uncomment the alter table.
If natural join looks appealing for other purposes, make sure you know the risks before you apply it elsewhere.
